# CKEditor setData makes the editor BLANK Firefox 9

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to edit formatted HTML in CKEditor but the problem is if I set the value dynamically then it's only viewable in the "SOURCE" mode, and it appears as a blank !

I've used

```
<textarea name="text2" id="text2"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
var str=document.getElementById('text2').value;
CKEDITOR.instances.text.setData(str);
```

and

```
CKEDITOR.instances.text.setData('<?php echo htmlentities($HTMLcode, ENT_QUOTES); ?>');
```

Sample data I've tried

```
<h3 style="color:blue;">
&lt;!-- T<strong>his </strong>webs<sup>ite a</sup>nd its conten<em>t is cop</em>yright<u> of </u><span style="color:#ff0000;">Sourav Ghosh 2011</span>.All rights <sub>reserved.Any redistribution or reproduction of part or all of the contents in any form is prohibited</sub>.This work is registered under Section 2 (o) of the Indian Copyright Act, 1957. For more you can visit <span style="font-size:36px;"><strong><u><span style="background-color:#ffff00;">http://copyright.gov.in</span></u></strong></span> --></h3>
```

---

Got the problem, here is the villain string

```
&lt;!--
```

and even this

```
<!--
```

But How can I set data containing any of the above string in CKEditor ?

Comment: What does the final generated code look like? The PHP source isn't really meaningful for this.

Comment: It's formatted HTML, but the editor appears blank, but if I click on the SOURCE button of the editor I can see the code.

Comment: but then the reason could be in the HTML, couldn't it? Can you show an example? Have you tried some totally simple HTML? (If it's the same problem then, then it's something else.)

Comment: I've updated my question, please review !

Comment: Why is the `&lt;!--` in there in the first place? I suppose basically, the editor shouldn't be interpreting that as a comment, but it seems to be doing so for some reason.

Comment: Well an user can insert whatever he wants to in the editor :) 

It looks like a bug in the editor.

Comment: @Saurav yeah. I can't get my head around the logic right now, but this may indeed be incorrect behaviour. You could use `htmlspecialchars()` twice, but that feels like an ugly hack... Maybe it's worth searching the CKEditor docs/forums whether this is intended behaviour.

Comment: Yup, just got this http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8687